# why is that when I use the <> in sql it is not getting the null value

Tags: sql, string, oracle, null

Example I have the following records on column_name "color": blue, red, green, null...
when I do a select query .. select * from table_name where color <> red...
The sql should return all records except those that have color red, right? Why is it not showing those value that have null as color? Thank you!

Comment: http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/misc/null.html Information about handling null values in Oracle

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, any comparison with `NULL` returns false. If you want to also get `NULL` rows, you'll have to explicitly ask for them:

```
color <> 'red' OR color IS NULL
```

Comment: Nitpick - comparison with NULL returns UNKNOWN. Of course, in many contexts, UNKNOWN is treated the same as FALSE anyway.

Comment: Well, the concept of a boolean in most SQL flavors is a bit odd anyways. Why couldn't they just have a proper boolean type and real true and false values? Always reminds me of how archaic SQL actually is, they probably based it on BASIC or whatnot...

Answer (score 0):

Use where isnull(color,'') <> 'red'

Null isn't a value. Same applies for avg, sum, etc.

Comment: In Oracle, '' is equivalent to NULL.

Comment: Then why doesn't it work? Is it because <> also means not null?

Comment: No, <> means "not equal to". Since NULL means "unknown", it is always unknown if anything is equal to, or not equal to, NULL.

Comment: So selecting null will return '' values but selecting '' will not return null values? I figured if null = '' then his script would be working?

Comment: No, `''` and `NULL` are syntactically the same in Oracle. They are equivalent. However, `NULL=NULL` is unknown (as is NULL<>NULL) because you can't know if NULL is equal to ANYTHING (including NULL itself!). For the same reason, `NULL=''` is unknown!

Comment: By the way, your statement "Null isn't a value" is spot-on.

Comment: `isnull()` is valid for SQL Server but not Oracle (The question has an oracle tag).  Use `NVL()` or the ANSI standard `COALESCE()` instead. [NULL-Related Functions in Oracle 11.2](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions002.htm#CJAFHIFF)

Comment: If you have taken any calculus courses , it is a bit similar to infinity concept there. You can not say infinity = infinity since you do not know if one of them is bigger. Same way unknown = unknown always return unknown. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_logic

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [SET ANSI_NULLS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx) for an understanding of why this happens.

> When SET ANSI_NULLS is OFF, the Equals (=) and Not Equal To (<>)
>   comparison operators do not follow the ISO standard. [...] a SELECT
>   statement that uses WHERE column_name <> XYZ_value returns all rows
>   that are not XYZ_value and that are not NULL.

**Update:** sorry this is for SQL Server and your question is Oracle, however I'll leave this here as it's probably still relevant.

Answer (score 0):

In Sql server to compare any value with null you have to use IS NULL or IS NOT NULL

So your query will be

```
Select * from table_name where color IS NOT NULL
```